# Language link always to the home

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I´m working on this website: www.canal.es/wordpress/

I´m using qtranslate and here it´s the code i´m using on the languages:

```
    <div id="language">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="?lang=es" <?php if (qtrans_getLanguage() == 'es') echo 'class="active"' ?>>ES -</a></li>
            <li><a href="?lang=ca" <?php if (qtrans_getLanguage() == 'ca') echo 'class="active"' ?>>CA</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The problem is that if I enter to any page/category/post of the website and I want to change the language to "CA" or viceversa, it gets the language but always returns to the homepage.

I want that the change of language happens on the same page, not return to the home. 
What i´m doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the current URL into the link with the `lang` parameter changed. You will have to figure out if the current URL already contains the parameter and then change it, otherwise just add it.